# Div contents extending size of page rather than scrolling its contents regardless of overflow attribute

Tags: html, css

I am blocking out a new page for my site that is going to be responsive with a sliding divide separating 2 columns. On the left column I have a couple vertically stacked divs, the bottom of which I want to scroll its contents when it overflows. I want only the div to scroll and not the entire page.

I have already set the `overflow-y` to `scroll` and while this does produce the scroll-bar it still expands the entire page rather than recognizing the edge of the window. I have a feeling it has to do with the parent containers size not being fixed and I thought setting it to `max-height: 100%;` would resolve this but it has not.

here is the jfiddle
[jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2rLm158/)

It is basically just a grab from my sandbox site [wtb.dsdcs.com](http://wtb.dsdcs.com/what-the-buc-live/) but it seems to behave the same in the jfiddle so it should suffice.

Just a disclaimer: there is a video the autoplays in both the website and jfiddle that I left intact in-case its container is part of the issue, so may need to turn down speakers.

Clarification: #PlayList is the element I wish to be able to scroll.

Comment: Make sure you apply the `overflow` property to the correct element.

Comment: as is shown in the jfiddle, it is.

Comment: Oh, thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: Try applying `overflow:auto;` to the `body` tag. Does that solve your problem or come close to solving it?

Comment: that makes the entire page scroll, I would like the page to be constrained to the browser window and just the elements scroll as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your `Playlist` class a height - (e.g 400px). Then, as you add more `a` items you should get a scrollbar. You can remove `max-height` as that won't be needed.

If you want a dynamic height of the playlist, that always takes up the remainder of the height, you could add a jQuery script:

```
var h1 = $(window).height();
var h2 = $('.videowrapper').height();
$('.playlist').height(h1-h2);
```

Since your `videoWrapper` is set to take up 50% of the height, the other approach could be to set your `playlist` to have the other 50%. So set it to `height: 50%`.

```
.playlist {    
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

**EDIT 17 Oct:**

The reason the above might not work with all browsers is probably because of your implementation. Like I said in the comments below, you shouldn't be using table-type display properties because they don't support `overflow` very well.

The W3C even say that the `overflow` property only applies to block-type elements [LINK](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-text-20101005/#text-overflow).
The MDN suggests the same [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

As such, implementing `overflow` on any `table`-type element will always be a tricky and risky approach as browser support issues or browser display inconsistencies should be expected. To get a fully supported solution, I'm afraid you'd have to try other display properties such as `flex` or `block`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to get a fully supported solution for `overflow` on table elements, and therefore such answer cannot be provided. The only real "solution" here that would actually solve your problem would be a complete (or partual) overhaul of your entire site.

However, I hope the above gave you hint of direction of what to do next and as such being an acceptable answer for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Setting a fixed height makes it so it will not work as the windows is re-sized and divider dragged.

Comment: I have to believe there is a pure markup or css answer to this simple problem. It basically just boils down to a to vertically stacked divs the first being fixed size, the second taking up remaing space but allowing its contents to scroll within the variable size. Even the actual jfiddle site seems to be able to do this with its 4 zones, the only JS they use is to handle the draggable separator like I do.

Comment: still no dice. I may just start over on my markup, I may have just over-complicated it.

Comment: It didn't work for you!? I just tested again and it works perfectly. I also resized the window and it's fine there too. http://i.imgur.com/2TgjqJz.png. Are you sure you did it right?

Comment: maybe its a browser formatting issue then, can u branch off a jfiddle for me?

Comment: It starts off correct, but as soon as I drag the divider it goes off page

Comment: Yeah that's because the divider removes the 50% height and overrides it with its' own.

Comment: You would think, and what I am trying to acheive is to have the bottom div take the remainder of the height regardless of the top divs height or the viewports height.

Comment: Yeah heights are a bit tricky actually, but there are ways to do this. I will say that your markup is a bit messy though, and it might be good to start over as you suggested earlier. For example, I noticed that your `playlist` class is spelled witha  capital L in your markup, but lowercase in the css. Small things like that can really be a nuisance further down the line.

Comment: Anyway, I showed you two ways to do this. So when and if you remake your markup, you'll know where to look. If my input has been helpful to you, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Oh, and by the way, you really should move your CSS outside your markup on a separate file.

Comment: Yea just to confirm that I hadn't lost my mind I simplified the issue and it works fine in a minimal mock-up https://jsfiddle.net/jrbu4yc8/ so I just screwed up somewhere along the way trying to hack things together as I designed them. This stuff makes me miss the days where `<table>` and frames were acceptable for organizing a webpage.

Comment: Unfortunately I thought this was the answer, and while it does work in most browsers, IE still renders it wrong, even in the simplified jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/jrbu4yc8/4/

Comment: It is the right answer. You ask how to make the bottom left div to scroll on overflow and not the entire page and that's what I wrote. Remember, questions on Stackoverflow should be reasonably scoped, and you cannot expect people to study your entire project to provide an answer that works specifically for your program in the way you've implemented it. Anyway, I had another look at your code and I don't think using table display-properties is a good solution here. I think that's what might be breaking it for you. Try using [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead

Comment: If you still have issues, post another question about how you can implement your boxes without facing the overflow issues. But as far as I'm concerned, the above answer is correct. So unless the above didn't help you whatsoever, please consider re-marking it as the accepted answer. Good luck! :)

Comment: Well an answer that isnt IE compatible isn't really an acceptable answer, its a crap browser but I must still account for its users. Flex is still mixed in its compatibility, I just went with block divs and my sliding divider code is now change the sizes for both the dive preceding and following it, getting rid of the need for one of them to be dynamic and thus eliminating my problem.

Comment: Read my edit to my original reply. I hope that helps! :)